# Mongoose loop through findOneAndUpdate condition statement

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lodash

I want to know if this part of code can be written differently, only with Mongoose helper methods of models ? Can I return a success and error if no stock are greater then 0 ?

```
ProductSchema.statics.substractStock = function (products) {
  _.map(products, updateStock)
  function updateStock(o) {
    mongoose.model('Product').findById(o._id, function (err, product) { 
      return product 
    }).then(function(productDB){
      if(productDB.stock > o.stock && productDB.stock > 0){
        mongoose.model('Product').findOneAndUpdate(o._id, {$inc: {stock: -(o.stock)}}, {},
          function (err, doc) {
              //return success ??
          }
        );
      } else {
        //return 'no update' 
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with an atomic update where you can ditch the initial `findById()` call and include the comparison logic

```
if (productDB.stock > o.stock && productDB.stock > 0) { ... }
```

within the query as in the following:

```
function updateStock(o) {
    mongoose.model('Product').findOneAndUpdate( 
        { 
            "_id": o._id,
            "$and": [
                { "stock": { "$gt": o.stock } } ,
                { "stock": { "$gt": 0 } }
            ]
        },
        { "$inc": { "stock": -(o.stock) } }, 
        { "new": true }, // <-- returns modified document
        function (err, doc) {
            // check whether there was an update
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i think it's a good way but it doesn't work, i need to change `findOneAndUpdate` to `findOne` ?? err and doc return null.

Comment: Then use `update()` which will return the write result and check wether there's been an update or not